# WPF listbox hierarchial item template

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a list box that is bound to hierarchial collection. The data has list menu items. There are two types of menus. First one is grouping menu, which will have child items. Second one is menu items which can be selected and this one does not have any children.

I have a property names HasChildren to distinguish between different type of menu. I want to apply different type of template for both types of menu. I want to show buttons for selectable(second) menus and tree view for menu with chidlren.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding UserMenus}">
                                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TreeViewItem ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" Header="{Binding Name}">
                                            <TreeViewItem.ItemTemplate>
                                                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                                                    <StackPanel>
                                                        <Button Width="250" Content="{Binding Name}" ToolTip="{Binding Name}" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignRaisedButton}"
                                                                Command="{Binding DataContext.TemplateCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox}}" CommandParameter="{Binding Id}"/>
                                                    </StackPanel>
                                                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                                            </TreeViewItem.ItemTemplate>
                                        </TreeViewItem>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            </ListBox>
```

I tried this approach but it is not working for top level menu items, it is displaying tree view item for both types of menus.

My hierarchial data class.

```
public class MenuModel : ObservableObject, IMenuModel
    {
        string _name, _description, _id;
        public MenuModel()
        {
            Children = new ObservableCollection<IMenuModel>();
        }
        public string Name { get => _name; set => SetProperty(ref _name, value); }
        public string Description { get => _description; set => SetProperty(ref _description, value); }
        public string Id { get => _id; set => SetProperty(ref _id, value); }
        public bool HasChildren
        {
            get
            {
                bool returnValue = false;
                if (Children != null && Children.Count > 0)
                {
                    returnValue = true;
                }
                return returnValue;
            }
        }
        public ObservableCollection<IMenuModel> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Help me to apply template properly to achieve desired result.

Comment: You can define different `DataTemplate` and use the ItemTemplateSelector to select the appropriate template. Check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplateselector?view=net-5.0)

Comment: I tried to do that i was not successful. children of a tree don't have button style. My data template definition is <DataTemplate x:Key="ButtonStyle">
            <Button Width="250" Content="{Binding Name}" ToolTip="{Binding Name}" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignRaisedButton}"
                    Command="{Binding DataContext.TemplateCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox}}" CommandParameter="{Binding TemplateId}"/>
        </DataTemplate>

Comment: and tree style is <DataTemplate x:Key="TreeStyle">
 <TreeViewItem x:Name="Tree"  Header="{Binding Name}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
</DataTemplate>

Answer (score 0):

You can try this：

Xaml

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding UserMenus}">
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate2" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
            <StackPanel>
                <Button Width="250" Content="{Binding Name}" ToolTip="{Binding Name}" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignRaisedButton}"
                        Command="{Binding DataContext.TemplateCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox}}" CommandParameter="{Binding Id}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate1">
            <TreeViewItem ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" Header="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.Resources>
</ListBox>
```

DataTemplateSelector

```
public sealed class MenuModelSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        if (item is MenuModel menuModel)
        {
            var resourceKey = menuModel.HasChildren ? "DataTemplate2" : "DataTemplate1";
            if (container is FrameworkElement element && element.FindResource(resourceKey) is DataTemplate dataTemplate)
            {
                return dataTemplate;
            }
        }

        return base.SelectTemplate(item, container);
    }
}
```